# Is the number of second convolution layer parameters correct?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have simple CNN for the MNIST data problem.

```
cnn_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=24, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=36, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

and this is how summary looks like:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 26, 26, 24)        240       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 24, 24, 36)        7812      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_13 (Flatten)         (None, 20736)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_26 (Dense)             (None, 128)               2654336   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_27 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,663,678
Trainable params: 2,663,678
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I have skipped pool layers in the problem for the simplicity of the question.

The first convolution layer has 240 parameters which is easy to calculate: (kernel size + bias) * number of filters: (3*3+1)*24.
Please explain me why second convolution layer has 7812 parameters (36 * 217).

The flatten layer has size of 20736. Which is the number of pixels produced by 36 filters of the previous layer: 24 * 24 * 36.

But how can we obtain 36 images by 36 filters from 24 images of the previous layer? Shouldn’t the size of the flatten layer be 36 * 24 * 24 * 24 which is the number of filters from the previous layer * size of the bitmap from the previous layer * number of filters from the first convolution layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of parameters for a convolutional layer is

```
(filter_height * filter_width * in_channels * out_channels) + out_channels
```

In your case, that's

```
(3 * 3 * 24 * 36) + 36 = 7,812
```

The output shape of such convolution is

```
(n_samples, remaining_height, remaining_width, n_filters)
```

Comment: Thanks. That explains a lot. Could you answer the second question?

Comment: I don't know what a bitmap is :)

Comment: I meant image - output of a single filter. Don't the two convolutional layers produce 24*36 images?

Comment: Every filter in second layer produce 24 images and then sum all of them to one feature map. Am I right?

Comment: Every filter transforms your image to 1 channel, and are concatenated on that axis. In the second layer, it's 36